# .Net installations are conflicting or not being picked up while in AWS CodeBuild windows environment

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, buildspec

We had a .NET code with version 6.0 residing in AWS Code Commit. We are trying to build the .NET code using AWS Windows code built in the Windows environment. Once the postcode is built, we need to pack the built code, and the generated APIs should be deployed to AWS Lambda. Previously we were doing all this build and deployment locally using manual steps with the `AspNetCore.2.0.9` & `dotnet-sdk-2.1.202` versions also installed. For this, we are using commands in our local after cloning repo.

1. `dotnet restore`
2. `dotnet lambda package --configuration release --framework net6.0 --output-package bin/release/net6.0/hello.zip`. After the zip is created, we use using following command to deploy the code to Lambda
3. `cd Test`
4. `sls deploy -r us-east-1 -s <stage> -v`

To automate this, we created a code build and code pipeline. For Code build following is the Buildspec we used and unable to achieve this through the pipeline and getting errors while building. Attached is the Buildspec and the errors below.

Build spec:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - Echo "Installing required versions of .Net.."
      - dotnet --version
      - Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1
      - .\dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel STS
      - $env:PATH = $env:PATH + ";$env:USERPROFILE\.dotnet" 
      - Echo "Installation completed..!"
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Entering pre_build phase.."
      - dotnet new install Amazon.Lambda.Templates::*
      - dotnet new install Amazon.Lambda.Tools
      - dotnet new install Amazon.Lambda.TestTool-3.1
      - dotnet new install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates
      - echo "Pre_build phase Completed..!"
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Running build commands now.."
      - cmd /c build.cmd
      - echo "Build completed now..!"
  post_build:
    commands:
      - ls "bin/release/net6.0"
artifacts:
  files:
    #- '**/*'

Error:-
[Container] 2023/09/05 09:05:17 Running command cmd /c build.cmd

C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src644877321\src\git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\test_API>dotnet restore 
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src644877321\src\git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\test_API\testAPI.csproj (in 12.35 sec).
  Restored C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src644877321\src\git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\test_API\test_API.csproj (in 13.7 sec).

C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src644877321\src\git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\v1\repos\test_API>dotnet lambda package --configuration release --framework net6.0 --output-package bin/release/net6.0/hello.zip 
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.nuget\packages\amazon.lambda.tools\2.2.0\lib\netcoreapp2.0\dotnet-lambda.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\

The following frameworks were found:
  3.1.32 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  6.0.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  7.0.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

[Container] 2023/09/05 09:05:40 Command did not exit successfully cmd /c build.cmd exit status 0x80008096
[Container] 2023/09/05 09:05:41 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/09/05 09:05:41 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cmd /c build.cmd. Reason: exit status 0x80008096
```

Comment: Please format your buildspec and read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344). It seems that your dotnet installations are conflicting or not being picked up, but you need to edit your question to be much more readable and formatted for us to be able to help.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Edited the subject and error of my question according to your suggestion. Could you please help me in finding the solution and solve my issue?

Comment: Can you please add full output e.g. I see `echo Installing required...` but not in the output. Can you also share the full contents of `build.cmd`? I'm 90% certain on the issue but need to make sure. And is this a preconfigured build env or customised? If customised, can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: hi @ErmiyaEskandary we are using the preconfigured build environment only. Not any customized one. Below are the commands that the Build.cmd file consists of.

dotnet restore
dotnet lambda package --configuration release --framework net6.0 --output-package bin/release/net6.0/hello.zip

I usually trigger the Build.cmd in local, and these two commands will execute successfully. In my view, it is expecting two .NET versions and those are missing in Preconfigured environment. Also tried installing in the environment. But throwing an error that these versions aren't supported by environment.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary So, what's your view on above issue and let me know for any possible ways! Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Is your .NET app multi version? If not, and you only need .NET 6, do `phases: // install: // runtime-versions: // dotnet: 6.x`. If that doesn't work, please add the exact contents of Build.cmd to the question, and split the scripts from the actual output. Also add the output you have when you run it locally to the question. And which preconfigured build environment Docker image are you using?